# Why javafx Image View on Button is not setting as expected

Tags: button, javafx, imageview, gallery

I making random image gallery in javafx using buttons. I am setting imageView to buttons as I need Images get clicked. The problem is imageView is not setting on button as expected. Buttons have pref height and width as 110.

[image: This is the Before Image note Buttons distance]

[image: This is after Image why distance is changed]

Below is the code am using to set imageView for buttons.

```
for(int i=0; i<35; i++){
    Button button = list.get(i);
    ImageView imageview =new ImageView(imageList.get(i));
    imageview.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageview.setFitHeight(110);
    imageview.setFitWidth(110);
    button.setGraphic(imageview);
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Do you want the padding(grey area around the image) to not be there?

Comment: You can see the space between buttons after and before adding imagview. I don't want that space to be changed as in second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the [`padding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#paddingProperty) of the `Button`s to empty:

```
Button button = new Button(null, imageView);

// quadratic grey background
button.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

// no padding
button.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
```